# "typedef typename" equivalente em C++03

Tags: c++, typedef

Bom dia. Estou tendo problemas com um código de uma biblioteca que quero adicionar ao meu projeto. Eu utilizo o Visual Studio 10, que já é um pouco antigo, com uma versão de C++ ainda mais. O código da biblioteca segue o formato:

```
struct MyStruct
    {
        private:
            typedef typename std::map< int, std::string > Type;

            Type m_Variable;
        public:
            typedef typename Type::const_iterator const_iterator;

            inline const_iterator begin() const { return m_Variable.begin(); }
            inline const_iterator end() const   { return m_Variable.end(); }

    };
```

Ao compilar, o seguinte erro aparece:

error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration

Como não há a possibilidade de atualizar a linguagem nesse caso, teria alguma forma equivalente de declarar Container e const_iterator?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: E por que não atualiza o VS?

Comment: A dor de cabeça de fazer isso para todos os colaboradores não compensa o esforço. Isto considerando que não haveria problemas de compatibilidade.

Comment: A dor de cabeça em usar algo com 20 anos de defasagem compensa? Então tá ok.

Comment: Cara vc tem que atualizar o compilador, isso são funcionalidades do c++ 11/17, sem atualizar o compilador não existe passe de magica.

Answer (score 0):

Cara mesmo ativando todas as funcionalidades do seu compilador o [visual studio 2010](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table/) não possui suporte pra [typename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename), pois é uma feature do c++11.